# Can I overload the throw keyword?

Tags: c#, exception, throw

I want to overload the *throw* keyword to catch a class which inherits from Exception and to have it do some logging and other stuff before the actual throw. Is this possible? Or do I have to use a regular function?

I've tried:

```
public class cSilException : Exception
    {
        private string m_strMsg;

        public override void throw(cSilException ex)
        {

        }
...
...
}
```

Comment: What is the use of it?

Comment: Keywords are not overridable nor overloadable.

Comment: Also if you could override throw you could see some unexpected result from underlying libraries. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you want to do is add a constructor to your exception and do whatever you need to do within that constructor.

```
public class cSilException : Exception
{
    //constructor
    public cSilException()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Your notion of "overloading the throw keyword" was quite, er, how to put it, *psychedelic*.

Of course, as many have pointed out, it is best to avoid doing this if your intention is to do things such as logging.  Alois Kraus has posted another answer with a very good suggestion.

Comment: Note that if you log the exception in the ctor, you very well may be seeing logged exceptions that were never actually thrown - only instantiated. For logging purposes, its better to have an extension/helper method `LogAndThrow`.

Comment: Also, exceptions may be caught and rethrown - in which case you will only see one log message.

Comment: And that works in C++ as well. Exactly the same way.

Answer (score 25):

Register the event `AppDomain.FirstChanceException.` There you get all exceptions before the are actually thrown. In the event handler you can check for your `exception` and do the required logging.

***No magic and no bad design.***

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException;
        DoBadThings();
    }

    private static void DoBadThings()
    {
        DoOneLevelBelow();
    }

    private static void DoOneLevelBelow()
    {

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    var invalidCast = (string)((object)i);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidTimeZoneException();
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if( e.Exception is InvalidCastException)
        {
            LogInvalidCast((InvalidCastException)e.Exception);
        }
    }

    private static void LogInvalidCast(InvalidCastException invalidCastException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got Invalid cast: {0}", invalidCastException);
    }
```

***This will lead to:***

> Got invalid cast: `System.InvalidCastException:` The object of the type
>   `"System.Int32"` cannot be converted to "System.String".    at
>   `ThrowTest.Program.DoOneLevelBelow()` in
>   d:\Media\Blog\ThrowTest\Program.cs:line 31.

Please note since you are getting the exception before the stack is unwound you will see only the method where it did happen but not the calling methods since the stack was not unwound yet. 
If you want the complete call stack you can use `Environment.StackTrace` to get all stack frames.

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't recommend logging anything inside the exception's constructor since it violates the single responsibility principle and is considered a bad design. Also, the fact that an exception was created doesn't necessarily mean it has been thrown, and besides, exceptions can be caught and rethrown - these things may lead to incorrect logging messages.

Instead, you can use an application-wide exception handler which will handle exceptions according to your predefined policy. For example, you can have a look at the [Enterprise Library Exception Handling Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440728(v=pandp.60).aspx) and specifically [this section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440728(v=pandp.60).aspx#sec18).

Answer (score 2):

You can't overload `throw` it is an integral part of the language (not a member of a class)

If you want to handle a specific Exception you should `catch` that exception:

```
try
{
    // your code, which throws some exceptions
}
catch(cSilException csEx)
{
   // handle csEx
   throw;  // rethrow this exception
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // handle all other exceptions
}
```

This code catches the special exception `cSilException`in a different code block than all other exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Look for methods and members of `Exception` class. You can define constructor for `cSilException` like this

```
public cSilException(string message)
{
    Message = message;
}
```

and than in `catch (cSilException ex)` do `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);`